# [__NSArrayI removeObjectAtIndex:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsarray, unrecognized-selector

I am trying to delete the row at specific index but I am getting this error. As it shows NSArray but I am using NSMutableArray. Somehow it is forcefully type casted.

These two arrays are declared globally.

```
NSArray *contacts;
NSMutableArray *sortedContacts;
```

In cellForRowAtIndexPath method, I am copying NSMutableArray in NSArray to show data in rows otherwise directly using NSMutableArray, key values missed.

```
contacts = [sortedContacts copy];
```

This is my button on row, on pressing it, I want to delete all row with data.

```
-(void)CancelButtonClicked:(UIButton*)sender
{
    CGPoint buttonPosition = [sender convertPoint:CGPointZero toView:self.tableView];
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForRowAtPoint:buttonPosition];
    [sortedContacts removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    [self.tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

Comment: @Larme He's not calling `removeObjectAtIndex` on `contacts`, though.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight: Good point. My question now is which line exactly causes the crash so.

Comment: @Larme I'm reasonably sure it's the call `[sortedContacts removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row]`, but at a point when `NSArray` is assigned to a variable that is supposed to hold a reference to a mutable array.

Comment: ... no doubt retrieved from `NSUserDefaults` :(

Comment: contacts is a NSArray not a variable.

Comment: Okay but how I can solve this issue. I am retrieving data from firebase.

Comment: why dont you make contact mutable?

Comment: @Larme "contacts = [sortedContacts mutableCopy]" is not working.

Comment: I am retrieving contacts from firebase and saved them in NSArray contacts. @Mr.T .It also has some keys. Therefore if I copy NSArray in to NSMutableArray, then keys become missed. Therefore,I retrieved data into NSMutableArray, as it is editable and copy it into NSArray "contacts" to show in tableview. As sortedcontacts is NSMutableArray but still when I want to remove object, it is forcefully typecasted.

Comment: Where do you set `sortedContacts`?

Comment: This is how sortedContacts are set in my code.     sortedContacts = [self.tempContactsDataDict objectForKey:self.tempSectionTitles[indexPath.section]];

Comment: May be it is related to "indexPath" because "indexPath" is stored as NSArray and that's why it is type casted  forcefully.

Comment: `[self.tempContactsDataDict objectForKey:self.tempSectionTitles[indexPath.section]]` seems to return a NSArray and not a NSMutableArray.

Comment: Yes, but you can store it in NSMutableArray.

Answer (score 1):

It's Just Simple Soultion If you want to remove first object of the Array Index than add this Line of your code.

```
data = [[dicsResponse valueForKey:@"data"]mutableCopy];

[data removeObjectAtIndex:0];
```

Answer (score 0):

I found this solution. Copy sortedconacts in NSMutableArray. After, removing object, copy the modified array in to original sortedcontacts array. :)

```
  -(void)CancelButtonClicked:(UIButton*)sender
  {
     NSMutableArray *copy=[sortedContacts mutableCopy];
     CGPoint buttonPosition = [sender convertPoint:CGPointZero toView:self.tableView];
     NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForRowAtPoint:buttonPosition];

    [copy removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    [self.tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
    [self.tableView reloadData];
    sortedcontacts=[copy mutableCopy];
  }
```

Comment: I was posting the same solution.... Got same crash rite now and solved it doing similar thing... :p

Comment: I do not know, somebody is reporting negative on my questions. This is very important question and many people solved it in similar ways. Please help me, otherwise I will be blocked.

Comment: I downvoted your answer as that is a ridiculous solution and should not be encouraged.  You should ensure that `sortedContacts` is mutable as soon as it's created and not do it while handling a button press.  It's a massive hack from someone who has lost control of their own code.

Comment: @Droppy. Everybody posted same answer. You have not faced this situation and you do not know that this is the only solution that exists. Search Google because before posting my question, I searched all stackoverflow and somebody wrote the same solution and I also thought in same way, you are thinking.

Comment: If by "Everybody posted same answer" you mean "everyone recommended using `mutableCopy`" then yes, they did, but not in button handling code, but rather in whatever code is used to populate the array in the first place.  You have not revealed how you populated the array in the first place, so the actual reason for the error could not be located.  Your answer won't help anyone at all.

Comment: Populating is not my issue at all. It tells nothing. You can populate in many ways.